# How do I create an OrderBy statement using a reflected value?

Tags: c#-4.0, reflection

I would like to create a method that orders an IEnumerable List by a given property where the property is passed into the method by a string i.e. (Mind you the first code example does not work, but the second does and is what I am trying to emulate dynamically).

```
string sortName = "SerialNumber";
IEnumerable<PartSummary> partList = FunctionToCreateList();
partOrderedList = partList.OrderBy(what do I stick in here);
```

that would be equivalent to

```
IEnumerable<PartSummary> partList = FunctionToCreateList();
partOrderedList = partList.OrderBy(p => p.SerialNumber);
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying you want to pass the order by in to your method? If so, you can use this:

```
Expression<Func<PartSummary, bool>> orderByClause
```

Then you can do this:

```
partOrderedList = partList.OrderBy(orderByClause);
```

Then you can handle your order by in your business layer or wherever you wish.

Okay, update: If you want to pass in the column name as a string you can do something like as follows:

Create a static class for an extension method (reference: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/39028ad2-452e-409f-bc9e-d1b263e921f6/):

```
static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string sortingColumn, bool isAscending)
    {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortingColumn))
        {
            return source;
        }

        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, String.Empty);

        MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, sortingColumn);
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(property, parameter);

        string methodName = isAscending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";

        Expression methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName,
                                            new Type[] { source.ElementType, property.Type },
                                            source.Expression, Expression.Quote(lambda));

        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(methodCallExpression);
    }
}
```

Then you can create  your method:

```
   static IQueryable<PartSummary> FunctionToCreateList()
    {
        IList<PartSummary> list = new List<PartSummary>();
        list.Add(new PartSummary
                     {
                         Id = 1,
                         SerialNumber = "A",
                     });
        list.Add(new PartSummary
                     {
                         Id = 2,
                         SerialNumber = "B",
                     });
        return list.AsQueryable();
    }
```

And then call your method:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IQueryable<PartSummary> partOrderedList = FunctionToCreateList();
        PartSummary partSummary = new PartSummary();
        string sortBy = "Id";

        partOrderedList = partOrderedList.OrderBy(sortBy, false);

        foreach (PartSummary summary in partOrderedList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(summary.Id + ", " + summary.SerialNumber);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Now you can pass in the column name as a string and sort.

Hope this helps!

Comment: sorry for being unclear....the orderby is inside the method and is what the method does.  I would like to pass in the name of the property that I would like the OrderBy to sort by.

Comment: It seems the source is not `IQueryable<T>`. But you can easily fix that by using `AsQueryable()`. Or by compiling the expression and using `IEnumerable<T>` overloads of the methods.

Comment: That looks really good.  Let me implement that and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid extending and just use a compiled expression tree to accomplish this:

```
    public Func<T, object> ResolveToProperty<T>(String propertyName)
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        var paramExpression = Expression.Parameter(t, "element");
        var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(paramExpression, propertyName);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(propertyExpression, paramExpression).Compile();
    }

    string sortName = "SerialNumber";
    IEnumerable<PartSummary> partList = FunctionToCreateList();
    var partOrderedList = partList.OrderBy(ResolveToProperty<PartSummary>(sortName));
```